# Cross join on a group based on the condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have Item and Exam tables -

[image]

My desire result -

[image]

I tried a lot but I am unable to join Exam table to Item table based on Code group.

Is it possible to cross join or any other join for these two tables to get the desire result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT A.Code, i.Item, A.Exam
FROM
(
SELECT Code,e.Exam
FROM Item i
CROSS JOIN Exam e
GROUP BY Code,e.Exam
) A
LEFT JOIN Item i ON i.Code= A.Code AND i.Exam = A.Exam
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way around generating the missing data.  The calendar table approach would be to cross join all codes with all exams.  Then, left join this table to `Item` and order to get the result you want:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM Item) AS C
   CROSS JOIN Exam
)
SELECT
    t1.Code,
    t2.Item,
    t1.Exam
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN Item t2
    ON t1.Code = t2.Code AND
       t1.Exam = t2.Exam
ORDER BY
    t1.Code,
    CASE WHEN t2.Item IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    t1.Exam
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Uh, instead of manually inserting the codes in the first CTE, a cross join on distinct codes would work (and for any number of codes there are, in case there's more than just the three in teh sample data). e.g. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM Item) AS C CROSS JOIN Exam`

Comment: @ZLK I mindlessly vomited out a calendar table without realizing it could be simplified.  I took your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This should produce what you need. I am using UNION to combine CROSS JOIN and item table and then group by to ensure NULLs are removed.

```
SELECT code, max(item) as item, exam
FROM 
(SELECT distinct i.code, null as item, e.exam FROM exam e cross join item i
union all
SELECT code, item, exam
FROM item) u
group by code, exam
order by code, exam
```